# Migrating Gmail account to new Google Apps email and leaving a copy behind

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, migration

I can't find an easy and reliable way to migrate my old emails from Gmail to Google Apps that will leave me with a backup copy on the original account.

Using Mail Fetcher, it migrates, but it doesn't allow me to keep the copy of emails in the old Gmail account. I need the old emails to stay around in the first Gmail account just in case I miss something after migration.

Is there a way or suggestion on how I can do this?

Comment: But this Mail Fetcher on Apps will not let you to keep copy of your emails in your old account. Having tried this, comes with the error "pop doesn't allow you to keep local copy" !

Comment: How about this? http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=21290 Seems it is possible? (via http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=21289)

Answer (score 3):

I've used the following tool for downloading the content of a Gmail / Google Apps mail account and restoring the emails to another account and found it works well.

[Gmail Backup](http://www.gmail-backup.com/download)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but worth a short. Head over to [POP/Forwarding settings](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#settings/fwdandpop) from your previous Gmail account. Select "Enable POP for all mail"

[image: POP Settings]

Now, add your previous Gmail account to your Google Apps mail account from your [Google Apps settings](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#settings/accounts). This will setup emails to be fetched periodically from your old account.  This should also import all your previous emails.

Answer (score 2):

I used Thunderbird to fetch the emails from my Gmail account. Then I added my Google Apps account in Thunderbird and drag-and-dropped the emails from my first account into my Google Apps account.