# Backup Google Apps email

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, backup

I am using Google Apps for email. Is there any way I can backup all the emails into another Gmail Account?

Please also let me know any alternative solution too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For new incoming emails:
In settings, Forwarding and POP/IMAP, add a forwarding address.
Also, you may want to set a filter "is:spam" then "Never send it to Spam" to also forward all emails. ( I prefer to have all my emails backed up, and manually remove spam later.)

For exisiting emails, first, in Google Apps email account, in settings, Forwarding and POP/IMAP, "Enable POP for all mail". then import them into your backup gmail account using POP3 in settings, Accounts and Import, "Import mail and contacts"

Important: In your main account, remember to select option to leave existing emails in your main account(In POP Download:, "2. When messages are accessed with POP keep  Mail's copy in the Inbox"), else the import will move all the emails into your backup account.

Also, this might help: [Migrating Gmail account to new Google Apps email and leaving a copy behind](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16532/migrating-gmail-account-to-new-google-apps-email-and-leaving-a-copy-behind)

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps for Business has built-in archiving. See details [here](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/security_discovery.html). Also, there are other services that offer Gmail backup, such as [Backupify](https://www.backupify.com/).